# linking 404.htm to .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, 404

I have an old 2004 Dreamweaver website built on HTML. Tired of the analytics telling me I have a lot of 404s, I created a 404.htm page. How do I link the code in .htaccess to it so it will show up, instead of a page not found text? Here is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chronologicalbiblestudies\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.chronologicalbiblestudies\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.chronologicalbiblestudies\.com\/chronologicalbiblestudies\.htm" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "Tired of the analytics telling me I have a lot of 404s" - But are these legitimate 404s or do they need "correcting", ie. caused by typos in requests or errors in internal links? 404s are a fact of managing a website - you cannot (or should not) simply make them "go away" if that is what you are implying.

Comment: When you say "link the code," are you saying that some of our code is showing a 404 when it should be showing content?

Comment: Mr. White, I don't mean to make them go away; I just want to help the visitor get to the right page if he typed in my site's address wrong or something went wrong with a link on my site.

Comment: Stephen Ostermiller, this is what comes back if I type blah on the end of my extension:  Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code inside your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

After that, you can test it by typing a non-existing page:

```
https://example.com/idontexist.html
```

Your **custom 404 page** should appear instead of just a page not found text